# How to get the type of the control using AssociatedControlID

Tags: c#, asp.net

My design is as follows:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ddl1">
</asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

like this I have several labels, I would like to find out the control type that is associated with each label on my form. Is it possible to get the control type?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw.aspx) and pass in the `AssociatedControlID`:

```
Control c = FindControl(lbl1.AssociatedControlID);
if(c == null) // Not found
else
{
    Type t = c.GetType(); // Gets the type of the control
    if(c is TextBox) // I'm a textbox
    else if(c is DropDownList) // I'm a DropdownList
}
```

Comment: Hi can we get which control it is by using this

Comment: @Vivekh, check the type with switch statement comparing with DropDownlist, TextBox, etc

Answer (score 0):

In code behind try this :

```
foreach (Label lbl in this.Page.Form.Controls.OfType<Label>()) 
{

}
```